# Software to burn full-sized images and thumbnails into one package

Tags: lightroom, publishing, thumbnails, dvd

I just helped shoot a wedding for the first time for some friends, and I'm going to burn a DVD for them.

Ideally, I want a DVD which contains both full-sized images and thumbnails, along with some kind of unbranded viewer that links the two. That is, like an HTML site would do where you get a page/screen of groups/folders, which when clicked display thumbnails, which when clicked display full-sized images. Where the full-sized files are stored in regular folders for easy copying or viewing directly with other tools. Multiple-size scaling would be nice too, but not necessary.

I guess this would be equivalent to what a good photo hosting site provides, only offline.

I have Lightroom 4 and attempted to use the Web module for this, but it doesn't seem to allow me to specify "full-sized", or to support folders in the output. (I'd also ideally like to create those groups on the DVD differently than how they're organized in LR, but I realize I can use some LR tools to create multiple organizations internally if necessary.)

I did search around the web and here, but haven't yet found anything that does what I'm envisioning. I'm primarily on Windows 7 but also have a Macbook in the home, so either platform would be acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

You best way to go for this is using an actual website. Put the images in 3 folders:

- thumb resolution
- screen resolution
- print resolution

Make a HTML file that has - for example- a chain of left-floating divs or a table if you prefer that.

```
<div style="float:left;"><a href="\screen\img1.png"><img src="\thumb\img1.png"> <a href="\print\img1.tiff">Full resolution</a></div>
```

Make it autostart with a [autostart software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735412/how-to-make-an-html-page-open-automatically-on-a-cd-dvd)

That way you have full control over the layout and everything else. The user does not need to run any software, and can copy the folders just like that

Comment: Yes, that's an option, but I was seeking something that wasn't all manual like this would be.

Comment: You can create an excel file where you put every image in one line and everytime you have a image file name you change to the next column. like that you can make a HTML file in 15 minutes.